# How can I parse a JSON string containing functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object which looks like this:

```
string str = '[
  {
    "name": "data-input1",
    "type": "Element [in]",
    "description": "data-input1",
    "getConnectorPosition": "function (element) { return {x: 0, y: Math.floor(element.rectangle.width / 2)} }"
  },
  {
    "name": "data-output1",
    "type": "Element [out] [array]",
    "description": "data-output1",
    "getConnectorPosition": "function (element) { return {x: Math.floor(element.rectangle.width), y: Math.floor(element.rectangle.height / 2)} }"
  }
  ]';
```

and I'd like to parse this string into an object.

I receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

when the method getConnectorPosition is invoked.

Reading previous questions I have understood that functions in JSON are not exactly "legal", and the error also suggests this.

How, exactly, can I correctly parse a JSON object which contains functions (as above) and then invoke those functions?

Comment: JSON is for data interchange. It will never support functions. You can write your own code to post-process your parsed objects. *edit* There's also the `reviver` parameter, which basically just makes post-processing a little simpler (sometimes).

Comment: Do you mean you want to parse this JSON string to JavaScript object?

Comment: @Roko I don't think this is a duplicate. The dupe asks if it's valid. This question comes with the assumption that it's invalid, and asks how to get around it.

Comment: *"I'd like to parse this string into a json"* It rather seems you want to parse the string **containing** JSON into an array of objects.

Comment: Okay, which browser are you using?

Comment: @minseong This is not a browser issue

Comment: @FelixKling as you said, I want to parse the string containing JSON into an array of objects. The browser is not important, because my code shuold run everywhere.

Comment: Why does the function definition have to be part of the your data?

Comment: @FabrizioMorello I want to know the browser so I can better understand your error - why do you have to be so rude about it? You could just answer the question and then give your opinion.

Comment: @meskobalazs I know that, but if I know the browser, I can figure out what the error means.

Comment: @minseong: I guess the OP does something like `arr[0].getConnectorPosition()`, which doesn't work since `getConnectorPosition` is a string.

Comment: @minseong  I apologize for browser stuff, I didn't want to be presumptuous, but I'm pretty sure that the problem is due to the presence of the function in the json object. Anyway, I use Chrome v 40.0.2214.91 m.

Comment: Check out the [jsonfn](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/jsonfn) library that's built for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is being thrown because in JavaScript you don't declare variables as a certain type, you always use the `var` keyword. If you change `string str` to `var str` then your current error will disappear.

You will then need to make sure your string is either single-line, or that you escape the literal newlines, as JavaScript can't handle multi-line strings:

```
     var str = '[\
        { "name": "data-input1", \
         "type": "Element [in]", \
```

Anyway, lets say you declare `str` correctly, and single-line or escape the newlines, you can parse it as normal:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

and access your functions *in string form* like so:

```
obj[0].getConnectorPosition;
```

To actually use your functions, you will have to evaluate them:

```
eval(obj[0].getConnectorPosition)
```

is the same as

```
function (element) { return { x: 0, y: Math.floor(element.rectangle.width / 2) } }
```

---

Update for the more-modern day (ES6+):

You can define variables using `let` and `const`, variables declared `const` cannot later be changed, and `let` is preferred to `var` because it is more scope safe.

You can also use template string literals to multi-line strings.

So you can write:

```
const str = `[
  {
    "name": "data-input1",
    "type": "Element [in]",
    "description": "data-input1",
    "getConnectorPosition": "function (element) { return {x: 0, y: Math.floor(element.rectangle.width / 2)} }"
  },
  {
    "name": "data-output1",
    "type": "Element [out] [array]",
    "description": "data-output1",
    "getConnectorPosition": "function (element) { return {x: Math.floor(element.rectangle.width), y: Math.floor(element.rectangle.height / 2)} }"
  }
  ]`;
```

Comment: It seems rational. Anyway, from this discussion I think that the best solution (in general) is to avoid the functions inside JSON if possible. Of course I have to thank you for effort, then I accepted this answer.

Comment: @FabrizioMorello Yes, there is generally a better approach to problems which would otherwise involve declaring functions within JSON, but all in all I think it is fairly safe to do that which I have described in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error you get is because you should write `var str = ...` instead of `string`.

You could get the substrings containing the function, and evaluate them as a function using `eval`. However this could lead to serious security and other concerns. To quote Douglas Crockford:

> The eval function (and its relatives, Function, setTimeout, and setInterval) provide access to the JavaScript compiler. This is sometimes necessary, but in most cases it indicates the presence of extremely bad coding. The eval function is the most misused feature of JavaScript.

If you really want to go down this road, you can do it using `eval`, but you have been warned :)

By the way, if you have parsed your JSON you could do this:

```
obj[0].getConnectorPosition = eval(obj[0].getConnectorPosition);
```

So you replace the previous string with the evaluated method.

Comment: Well, technically his example just contains strings, so this can definitely be parsed.

Comment: @meskobalazs I really want to stay away from 'eval' :)

Comment: @FabrizioMorello so you want to eval something but you don't want to `eval`. It's weird.

Comment: Then do not pass functions this way, I see no reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that converts a json string containing a function back to a json object with a valid function declaration.

```
var jsonstring = "{\"schema\": {\"title\": \"User Feedback\",        \"description\":\"so\", \"type\":\"object\", \"properties\":{\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}}," + "\"options\":{ \"form\":{\"attributes\":{}, \"buttons\":{ \"submit\":{ \"title\":\"It\", \"click\":\"function(){alert('hello');}\" }}} }}";

var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonstring);

function Iterate(data)
{
      jQuery.each(data, function (index, value) {
        if (typeof value == 'object') {
            Iterate(value);
        }
        else {
            if (value.indexOf("function()") > -1)
                data[index] = eval("(" + value + ")");
        }
    });

};

Iterate(jsonData);
//call the embedded function 
jsonData.options.form.buttons.submit.click();
```